# What if Lightning is not enabled for the Org at all by October?

Tags: lightning, release

I know this question may find people questioning lot of things.

But I am working on a very old org, which has lot of custom built applications(we hit the limits of customisation very close) built as the technology evolved. I don't blame the developers for it. It seemed perfect thing at that moment. Things like:

- Javascript
- JQuery
- AngularJS 1
- AngularJS 4
- ReactJS
- Applications built by external vendors

The primary issues that we are facing now, when we enable lightning is:

- RemoteAction in VF Pages are not supported
- JS Manipulating window object(window.location) does not work
- Lot of custom buttons/links on Page Layout needs to be reconsidered

I am sure if this was a small org, it was a easy thing to do. But this is a huge technical due if we start migrating. And as you know, business does not invest money in something that does not produce value. A new UI is not something many people would be interested in the org.

The only solution at the moment is to "**NOT ENABLING LIGHTNING AND FORCE ALL USERS TO CONTINUE WITH CLASSIC**". And if we do enable Lightning, Users are switched automatically to Lightning without their consent. Which is again a strange thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Lightning does not mean that you will lose access to Classic. Users will still be able to access Classic.

> Access to Salesforce Classic remains.

If you don't want to enable the Users to LEX, then make sure you don't enable the required permission:

> Custom profiles without the Lightning Experience User permission won't have access to Lightning Experience.

You can find more details on this critical update on the knowledge article [Turn On Lightning Experience critical update FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000273853&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: yes, that would cause lot of confusion. As they are switched automatically to Lightning, without their consent.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can disable the LEX permission. You can find more on the FAQ link and can reach out to Salesforce, they are the best resource for any additional help that your Org will need.

Comment: thanks @jayant  I wish Salesforce was able to support other frameworks before Aura/LEX came into picture :)